# File read in multipart post in cherrypy is always empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-post, httprequest, cherrypy

I'm having trouble reading the contents of a file sent to a cherrypy server as a part of a multipart POST request. I'm using the Python 'requests' module to create the request. The contents of of the file sent is always empty when parsed in cherrypy although the length is reported to be non-zero.

Python version for the server: 3.6.8

cherrypy version: 18.6.0

requests version: 2.18.4

The request is made through

```
response = requests.post(<url>, files={'file': open('slask.txt', 'rb')}, data={'name': 'some_name'}, verify=False)
```

where `<url>` is a valit url to the server.

`slask.txt` is a file that reads `b'slask \r\n'` when read through `open('slask.txt', 'rb').read()`

Code for the cherrypy server:

```
import os
import io
import cherrypy

cherrypy.server.socket_host = '<url>'

class ServerExample():
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Cherrypy server to manage something ..."
                                                                                             
    @cherrypy.expose
    def upload(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                            
        image = cherrypy.request.params['file']
        print(image.filename)
        print(image.fp.fp.rfile)
        print(image.fp.fp.remaining)
        print(image.fp.length)
        print(image.read())
        print(cherrypy.request.params['name'])
        
        return "parsed file..."

cherrypy.quickstart(ServerExample())
```

The response of the server is `200 "parsed file..."`.

The output of the server is:

```
Image filename: slask.txt
Underlying data object: <cheroot.makefile.StreamReader name=5>
Value of field 'remaining' in underlying data object: 0
Image length: 247
Image content: b''
Contents of multipart data field 'name': some name
<obfuscated> - - [27/Feb/2021:10:20:50] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "" "python-requests/2.18.4"
```

As can be seen the fields of the request are in place. However, the `read()` method of the `Part` object yeilds an empty result although its `length` is `247`. What is strange is that the underlying data object has `remaining` bytes `0` although no bytes have been read.

The request itself has been independently verified through making the exact same request to http://ptsv2.com where it can be shown that it contains all the intended info.

How am I supposed to read out the file contents of the variable `image`?

Comment: It appears you're looking for `image.file.read()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38998044/595220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments to the question, the way to access the binary data associated with an uploaded part is through `cherrypy.request.params['key'].file.read()`.